# Scala class instance variable consists of two maps?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to understand a data structure in some Scala code I'm reading (license is Apache and this is only a tiny excerpt). It's the nature of *pools* below that interests me. What does it mean for a data structure to be 2 separate maps/arrays/lists?

```
class TaskQueueAsync( numThreads: Int, queuesSize: Int ) extends TaskQueue
{
  private val lock  = new ReentrantReadWriteLock( true )
  private val pools = ( 1 to numThreads )
                      .map( _ => new ArrayBlockingQueue[Runnable]( queuesSize, true ) )
                      .map( q => new ThreadPoolExecutor( 1, 1, 1, DAYS, q,
                                  new BasicThreadFactory.Builder()
                                      .namingPattern( "indexer-%d" )
                                      .build(),
                                  ( task, executor ) =>
                                      if( !executor.isShutdown )
                                        executor.getQueue.put( task ) ) )
```

Could I get some help understanding what's is going on here? How is *pools* set up? What does it look like? (Maybe, "what does it look like in Java?")

Comment: What makes you say this is two separate [something]s? Are you looking at the two `map` calls? That's "map" in the functional programming "apply function to every element" sense, not the "key-value lookup data structure" sense.

Comment: I'm new to Scala. What makes me say anything about this is a complete lack of acquaintance with this language. I'm trying to figure out what 'pools' looks like and how it's set up. I get what map() does since it exists more or less in Java 8, but I still cannot conceive 'pools'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll try to annotate the `pools` logic and hopefully that will help:

```
private val pools =
  // start with a range from 1 to numThreads, which you can essentially
  // consider a Seq(1, 2, 3, ..., numThreads)
  ( 1 to numThreads )
      // now, for each value in that range, pass it to this function and store
      // the results in another sequence. The function ignores the input value
      // (which is what the _ means before the arrow) and returns a
      // new ArrayBlockingQueue[Runnable]. After this step, we will have
      // a Seq[ArrayBlockingQueue[Runnable]], with a number of elements
      // equal to numThreads
      .map( _ => new ArrayBlockingQueue[Runnable]( queuesSize, true ) )
      // Again, for each of these ArrayBlockingQueues, pass it to this
      // new function (captured in the q argument) and create a new Seq
      // of the results. In this case, it is a Seq[ThreadPoolExecutor]
      // where each of the ThreadPoolExecutor objects has been through the
      // initialization code below
      .map( q => new ThreadPoolExecutor( 1, 1, 1, DAYS, q,
                              new BasicThreadFactory.Builder()
                                  .namingPattern( "indexer-%d" )
                                  .build(),
                              ( task, executor ) =>
                                  if( !executor.isShutdown )
                                    executor.getQueue.put( task ) ) )
```

So the final resulting type of `pools` should be `Seq[ThreadPoolExecutor]`, and it will have a number of elements equal to numThreads. Hopefully that helps clarify what's happening.

Comment: Thanks. This was the elucidation I needed.